# constraints foreign key pros

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints

so besides just naming a foreign key, is there any real advantage creating a constraint foreign key instead of a normal foreign key?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. A foreign key is always a constraint. There are no other *normal* foreign keys.

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between using `references` as a column constraint inside a `create table` and adding an FK using `alter table T add constraint ...`?

Comment: @muistooshort yes, that's what i'm asking, sorry about my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for adding an foreign key using [`references` inside a `create table` statement is](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html):

```
[ CONSTRAINT constraint_name ]
REFERENCES reftable [ ( refcolumn ) ]
[ MATCH FULL | MATCH PARTIAL | MATCH SIMPLE ]
[ ON DELETE referential_action ] [ ON UPDATE referential_action ]
```

and using [`alter table ... add constraint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html):

```
[ CONSTRAINT constraint_name ]
FOREIGN KEY ( column_name [, ... ] ) REFERENCES reftable [ ( refcolumn [, ... ] ) ]
[ MATCH FULL | MATCH PARTIAL | MATCH SIMPLE ]
[ ON DELETE referential_action ] [ ON UPDATE referential_action ]
```

That only functional difference is that the `alter table` form lets you create foreign keys that use more than one column.

Of course you can use the `alter table` form inside `create table` as a table constraint rather than a column constraint:

```
create table T (
    ...
    foreign key (c1, c2) references T2(c1, c2)
)
```

In all cases, the underly foreign keys are the same, the only difference is where you define them.